# When should I derive a class from QObject?

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a Qt application and I am wondering if there are any benefits to create `QObject` classes other than adding signals and slots to them.

Comment: the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) have a list of what QObjects can do

Comment: one major thing is the ability to use Q_INVOKABLE and Q_PROPERTY macros to script your objects from QML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides assigning signal/slot features, QObject also add a few number of reflection capabilities on C++ classes.

If you want to add a subset of a QObject you can use Q_GADGET, which add some of the reflection features and things like Q_ENUM, Q_PROPERTY, etc.

The docs has more information about [it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_GADGET)

Comment: C++ with reflections is new to me !?

Comment: Qt adds some reflection capabilities through the MOC: Meta Object Compiler, Qt code is not standard C++ code, that's why it requires a Meta Compiler to run before.

Comment: Qt code is standard c++. The moc just generates code in addition to the self-written code, both are standard-conformant.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That it what I was looking for, I am going to look for those special properties. Thanks for the `Q_GADGET` tip too!

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld well, so try to compile Qt code with signals/slots without using MOC, the code generated by MOC is standard C++, indeed... but not the code you write.

Comment: @danielfranca: it is standard c++ code, it's just incomplete :) (without moc one would get undefined symbol linker errors, but no compilation errors)